# How to enforce copy elision in C++20?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, language-lawyer, c++20, return-value-optimization

C++17 promised to introduce Copy Elision as a requirement, so I've upgraded from C++14 all the way to C++20.  Just for that.  (RVO as an optional behavior-altering optimization... makes me genuinely motion-sick when running a program in my head.)  I'm very new to this version of C++, but I want to prescribe the behavior of returning an object completely; whether it calls it's copy method and a temp's destructor, or does not.

```
Object f() {
    Object x;
    x.value = 10;
    x.str = "example function";
    return x;
}
```

Is there anything special I must do (or change) in this `f()` function to ensure the returned object always elides calling it's copy or move constructor and `x`'s destructor?  Also, is there any way to ask the compiler to abort compilation if it can't do so?  I don't want to accidentally give the compiler the ability to choose, if I can help it.

Comment: Your code snippet requires NRVO (named return value optimization), which is not guaranteed. You could do `return Object{10, "example function"};` (assuming an `Object` can be created that way), and that will trigger mandatory RVO.

Comment: @cigien - I had no idea it was that easy, that's a fair requirement thank you!

Comment: If the constructor is not `explicit` you can even do `return {10, "example function"};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [cppreference's page on copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). Since C++17, there is a guaranteed form and a non-mandatory form. Technically, guaranteed copy elision is not even considered copy elision anymore, it is simply a change in the specification of [prvalues](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category).

"Guaranteed copy elision" happens when initializing an object (including in a return statement) with a prvalue of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification). By definition, a prvalue has no name, and so, before C++17 and in the case of a return statement, this was an non-mandatory optimization called unnamed return value optimization (URVO). Since C++17, it is replaced by a fundamental change in the language:

> a prvalue is not materialized until needed, and then it is constructed directly into the storage of its final destination.

In your code, `x` is named, so it is not a prvalue, and as such its copy (or move) is not guaranteed to be elided. Nevertheless, I believe most modern compilers will perform copy elision in this case, unless you specifically ask them not to (for example with `-fno-elide-constructors` for GCC and Clang). It is called named return value optimization (NRVO), and it is one of only two optimizations that may change the observable side-effects. Note that NRVO is forbidden in the context of a constant expression.

If you want a guarantee that no copy or move is performed, then you need to handle a prvalue instead:

```
Object f() {
    int value = 10;
    std::string str = "example function";
    return Object(value, str); // this is a prvalue being returned
}

// simpler
Object f() {
    return Object(10, "example function");
}

// even simpler if Object's constructor is implicit
Object f() {
    return {10, "example function"};
}
```

Comment: Off Topic: For those interested, the other optimisation which is allowed to change the observable side effects is https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Allocation

Answer (score 1):

#### Optional NRVO

The example that you've shown is an example of Named Return Value Optimization (NRVO). In such a case, the compiler is allowed to, but not required to perform copy elision. This means that the copy/move constructor of `Object` *may* be called, but it *may* also be omitted.

> [...] called *copy elision*, is permitted in the following circumstances (which may be combined to eliminate multiple copies):
>
> - in a `return` statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile object with automatic storage duration [...] with the same type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the object directly into the function call's return object.

- [[class.copy.elision] p1, p1.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision#1.1)

C++17 and C++20 have the same rule in this regard.

#### Mandatory RVO

What actually changed in C++17 is that plain Return Value Optimization (RVO) became mandatory. This kicks in whenever you `return` a prvalue, such as:

```cpp
Object f() {
    return {10, "example function"};
}
// or in C++20, with designated initializers
Object f() {
    return {.value = 10, .str = "example function"};
}
```

In these two cases, a C++17 compiler is *required* to elide the copy:

> [...]; the `return` statement initializes the returned reference or prvalue result object of the (explicit or implicit) function call by copy-initialization from the operand.

- [[stmt.return] p2](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return#2)

This means that `return { ... };` works as if you wrote `Object x = { ... };` at the call site; and for copy-initialization:

> If the initializer expression is a prvalue and the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as the class of the destination, the initializer expression is used to initialize the destination object.

- [[dcl.init.general] p16.6.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#16.6.1)

This rule means that the `{ ... }` initializes the `Object` at the call site directly. The two rules combined imply return value optimization.